# How to impute values in a column and overwrite existing values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to learn machine learning and i need to fill in the missing values for the cleaning stage of the workflow. i have 13 columns and need to impute the values for 8 of them. One column is called Dependents and i want to fill in the blanks with the word missing and change the cells that do contain data as follows: 1 to one, two to 2, 3 to three and 3+ to threePlus.

Im running the program in Anaconda and the name of the dataframe is train

```
train.columns
```

this gives me

Index(['Loan_ID', 'Gender', 'Married', 'Dependents', 'Education',
       'Self_Employed', 'ApplicantIncome', 'CoapplicantIncome', 'LoanAmount',
       'Loan_Amount_Term', 'Credit_History', 'Property_Area', 'Loan_Status'],
      dtype='object')

next

```
    print("Dependents")
    print(train['Dependents'].unique())
```

this gives me

Dependents
['0' '1' '2' '3+' nan]

now i try imputing values as stated

```
def impute_dependent():
my_dict={'1':'one','2':'two','3':'three','3+':'threePlus'};
return train.Dependents.map(my_dict).fillna('missing')



def convert_data(dataset):
    temp_data = dataset.copy()
    temp_data['Dependents'] = temp_data[['Dependents']].apply(impute_dependent,axis=1)
return temp_data
```

this gives the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-ccb1a5ea7edd> in <module>()
      4     return temp_data
      5 
----> 6 train_dataset = convert_data(train)
      7 #test_dataset = convert_data(test)

<ipython-input-46-ccb1a5ea7edd> in convert_data(dataset)
      1 def convert_data(dataset):
      2     temp_data = dataset.copy()
----> 3     temp_data['Dependents'] = 
temp_data[['Dependents']].apply(impute_dependent,axis=1)
      4     return temp_data
      5 

D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, 
axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6002                          args=args,
   6003                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6004         return op.get_result()
   6005 
   6006     def applymap(self, func):

D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
   250         # wrap results

D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in 
apply_series_generator(self)
     275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

TypeError: ('impute_dependent() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was 
given', 'occurred at index 0')
```

i expected one, two , three and threePlus to replace the existing values and missing to fill in the blanks

Comment: It's better to build a dict: `my_dict={'1':'one',...}` and then use `df.col.map(my_dict)`.

Comment: i didnt think of that so my_dict={'1':'one','2':'two','3','three','3+':'threePlus'} but what about nan values and would the df.col.map(my_dict) become train.Dependants.map(my_dict)

Comment: i tried this but its not working                                def impute_dependants(cols):
    Dependents = cols[0]
    
    if pd.isnull(Dependents):
            return "missing"
        else
        my_dict={'1':'one','2':'two','3','three','3+':'threePlus'}
    
train.Dependants.map(my_dict)

Comment: @QuangHoang i tried this but its not working def impute_dependants(cols): Dependents = cols[0] if pd.isnull(Dependents): return "missing" else my_dict={'1':'one','2':'two','3','three','3+':'threePlus'} train.Dependants.map(my_dict)

Comment: `def impute_dependent(): my_dict={'1':'one','2':'two','3','three','3+':'threePlus'}; return train.Dependants.map(my_dict).fillna('missing')`

Comment: @QuangHoang im getting this as an error File "<ipython-input-32-c43ade5b2473>", line 2
    my_dict={'1':'one','2':'two','3','three','3+':'threePlus'};
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Update your question with new code and errors.

Comment: @QuangHoang i just did

Comment: @QuangHoang i just updated the question again it appears ther was a speling mistake in dependents but when i changed it the error was still there

Comment: @QuangHoang i just noticed it was a comma instead of a : but now theres a problem with the next function when it calls the last one

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
my_dict = {'1':'one','2':'two','3':'three','3+':'threePlus', np.nan: 'missing'}
def convert_data(dataset):
    temp_data = dataset.copy()
    temp_data.Dependents = temp_data.Dependents.map(my_dict)
    return temp_data
```

As a side note, part of your problem might be the use of `apply`: essentially `apply` passes data through a function and puts in what comes out. I might be wrong but I think your function needs to take the input given by apply, eg:

```
def impute_dependent(dep):
    my_dict = {'1':'one','2':'two','3':'three','3+':'threePlus', np.nan: 'missing'}
    return my_dict[dep]

df.dependents = df.dependents.apply(impute_dependents)
```

This way, for every value in `df.dependents`, apply will take that value and give it to `impute_dependents` as an argument, then take the `return`ed value as output. As is, when I trial your code I get an error because `impute_dependent` takes no arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help the solution you gave works perfectly, if i may ask a tangential question when encoding for an algorithm say a random forest does the numeric value matter to much in this case for the credit history column i am given a 1 for good or a 0 for bad are these just labels to identify them there are missing entries in the column and im not sure of a logical way to infer what they should be so would imputing a 2 for unknowns mess with the data in some way or is that an acceptable way to mark an unknown in this case